# Django Admin - Change field model and automatically update another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Well, I have a `VagasUsuarios` model and a `Questionario` model. I would like that when I updated the `Questionario.pontuacao_questionario` field via django admin, my other `VagaUsuarios.pontuacao_vaga` field would be updated as well. Is there a way to do this?

thanks for listening =)

My Models:

```
class Questionario(models.Model):
    usuario                 = models.ForeignKey(Contas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [...]
    pontuacao_questionario  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Pontuacao do Questionário")
```

```
class VagasUsuarios(models.Model):
    usuario                 = models.ForeignKey(Contas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [...]
    pontuacao_vaga          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Pontuacao da Vaga")
```

Comment: I think reading this article will solve your problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/).

Example:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Questionario, VagasUsuarios


@receiver(post_save, sender=Questionario)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    obj = VagasUsuarios.objects.get(...)
    obj.pontuacao_vaga = instance.pontuacao_questionario
    obj.save()
```

Another is to override the `save()` (or rather `clean()`) method of your model and when it gets updated to fetch all the relevant `VagasUsuarios`-objects you want to update and update them.

Note on `clean()`: You got to call the clean-method yourself unless you are using the Django admin.